# Finding the annual yield of an investment with a changing interest rate

Tags: finance, actuarial-science

Let's say that  there was a variable annual effective interest rate on a capital invested for two years that followed these changes:

i(t) =
2%, t ∈ [0, 0.5),
3%, t ∈ [0.5, 1.5),
0.5%, t ∈ [1.5, 2]

How would I approach trying to find the annual yield of this investment given the structure of this interest rate? I know that taking an average of the interest rates won't work but it will come close. Thanks.

Comment: Is the interest paid every year or every two years?

Comment: @janosch Apologies, it is an annual effective rate. I have edited it now.

Comment: But then you should be able to average the interest rates within every year, shouldn't you?

Comment: @janosch If i average the rates, I have a rate of 2.5% over the first year, and then a rate of 1.75% over the second year. 1 unit of capital under these rates would amount to 1.0429375. This is equivalent to an effective rate of 0.02146875, i.e 2.15% p.a. The answer, I've been told, is 2.12%.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format posts on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would apply the $\color{grey}{\texttt{geometric mean}}$ to calculate the  annual yield. In my view there is no need to use the fractional part of an interest rate since there is only one payment.

The result is very close to $2.12\%$

$$\sqrt{1.02^{0.5}\cdot 1.03^1\cdot 1.005^{0.5}}-1=1.0211985-1=0.0211985\approx 0.0212=2.12\%$$

Answer (score 2):

Assume the initial investment is $1$.

Let $r$ be the effective annual yield based on the given specs.

Then $r$ must be such that $(1+r)^2$ equals the total return, hence
$$
(1+r)^2=\left(1+\frac{.02}{2}\right)\left(1+\frac{.03}{1}\right)\left(1+\frac{.005}{2}\right)
$$
which gives $r=.02122512210$.

Comment: But that would imply a mix of annual and biannual compounding, would't it?

Comment: When applying "stated" annual rates to a period other than one year, the accepted meaning is that the rate for the period is the annual rate linearly adjusted by the ratio of the period length to one year.

Comment: I think that is the same, but thanks for the clarification!